# Using Tkinter GUI this is client code . I am unable to send multiple data

Tags: python, tkinter

This is code for client in a chat server including GUI made using `Tkinter` in python.
The problem is that when I send message once then there is infinite loop which runs and does not allows me to send another message. Please tell me whats wrong in here.

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket#for sockets
import sys  #for exit
import tkMessageBox
blue ="#000fff000"

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
root.geometry("500x500")
e=NONE

# create dgram udp socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print 'Failed to create socket'
    sys.exit()

host = 'localhost';
port = 40019;

def sendmsg():
 global e
 e = Entry(frame ,width=50 )
 e.pack(side=RIGHT)
 e.focus_set()
 b = Button(frame, text="send", width=10, command=callback ,bg =blue)
 b.pack(side=LEFT)
 mainloop()
 text = e.get()

 def callback():
     print  e.get()
     msg=str(e.get())
     e.delete(0, END)
     while(1):          

      text_area.insert(END,msg)

      try:
        #Set the whole string
       while(1):
        s.sendto(msg, (host, port))             

        # receive data from client (data, addr)
        d = s.recvfrom(1024)
        reply = d[0]
        addr = d[1]

        print 'Server reply : ' + reply
        text_area.insert(END,reply)

      except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()            

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="SEND A MESSAGE", command=sendmsg)
filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=sys.exit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="SEND", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
text_area = Text(frame)
text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM)

B1 = Button(root, text = "CLOSE", command = sys.exit)
B1.pack(side =TOP)        

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe [update_idletasks()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) can help

Comment: @shaktimaan: no. update_idletasks is a band-aid for a badly designed program. Tk applications should be event oriented. Arrange to be notified when new data arrives on the socket. You can use a thread for your I/O but something like Twisted is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In any windowing system you have to keep processing the window system events regularly. This means using non-blocking I/O or doing netowork I/O on worker threads. You may also have to take care about updating UI windows from worker threads so a framework like twisted which integrates various event sources into one event processing loop can help to keep things working and simple.

A good example of a thread based scheme for integrating network and Tkinter is [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82965-threads-tkinter-and-asynchronous-io/). Note the worker thread queues data to be handled by polling from the UI thread when the UI thread is ready to process it.

I happen think the [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#auto16) package is a good way to handle this as this comes out more like Tcl's fileevents which integrate I/O events into the same event system as the UI events.